# Lualatex doesn't generate correct pdf that can be opened in Adobre Reader DC

Tags: tikz-pgf, luatex, animate

I have a strange problem with which I do not know the advice. I have simple code:

MNWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{animate}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \animategraphics[controls,autoplay,loop]{2}{mai_fig022}{}{}
  \caption{text}
\end{figure}
```

\end{document}

With Lualatex: `lualatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -halt-on-error -shell-escape mnwe.tex` I am able to produce animation, which works better in Foxit Reader ver. 8.3.2.25013, but in Adobe Reader DC release 2017 ver. 2017.012.20098. doesn't work completely! Built-in Javascript complains, see below:

[image: Adobe Reader and enabled JavaScript Debuger]

In Foxit Readar I obtain something, which works, but also in strange way. The animation is **constantly accelerating**.

Mai_fig022 is generated from this code by pdflatex:

```
% This animation helps explain the geometric interpretation of the 
% definite integral.
% http://texample.net/tikz/examples/animated-definite-integral/

\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz, pgf}
\usepackage{multido}

\begin{document}
%
\multido{\n=1+1}{20}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.25]
    \draw[red,thick,<->] (-1,1) parabola bend (0,0) (2.1,4.41)
        node[below right] {\(y=x^2\)};
    \draw[loosely dotted] (-1,0) grid (4,4);
    \draw[->] (-0.2,0) -- (4.25,0) node[right] {\(x\)};
    \draw[->] (0,-0.25) -- (0,4.25) node[above] {\(y\)};
    \foreach \x/\xtext in {1/1, 2/2, 3/3}
    \draw[shift={(\x,0)}] (0pt,2pt) -- (0pt,-2pt) node[below] {\(\xtext\)};
    \foreach \y/\ytext in {1/1, 2/2, 3/3, 4/4}
    \draw[shift={(0,\y)}] (2pt,0pt) -- (-2pt,0pt) node[left] {\(\ytext\)};
    %
    \def\mc{\n*\n}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\result{int(\n*\n*\n)}
    \shade[top color=blue,bottom color=gray!50]
        (0,0) parabola (0.1*\n,0.01*\mc) |- (0,0);
    \node[draw, fill=white] at (3cm,2cm) 
      {\(\int\limits_0^{\frac{\n}{10}}\!\!x^2\mathrm{d}x = 
       \frac{\result}{3000}\)};
    \draw[fill=black,color=black] (0.1*\n,0.01*\mc) circle (1.2pt);
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

Note: From this code, I obtain pdf with 20 pages and it is used in command `\animategraphics` in the MNWE code.  I use up to date Miktex system.

**Link for [Log File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzP8spWKnOvnLUpXcWt2TUFGb1U/view?usp=sharing) of the Luatex compilation:.*

Comment: Works ok for me. Can you show the log-file of the lualatex compilation?

Comment: Works for me, using TeXLive, updated this morning.

Comment: Works for me with Adobe Reader on Mac OS, whether compiling with `pdflatex` or `lualatex`, TeXLive 2017, up to date.

Comment: Thank you for testing. I use windows 10. Do you mean that it could be system issue?

Comment: Besides some packages not being up to date (`l3kernel`, `animate`, etc.), I can read in your log file `* pdfbase warning: "rerun" ... * Rerun to get internal references right!`.

Comment: I update Miktex system by using Miktex Update utility. If I understand it well, something is wrong in my installation and I should reinstall it. May I right?

Comment: For a thorough MiKTeX update, first do a "Synchronise Package Database" and then the usual  update of packages. Then, run `lualatex` until all rerun-messages have gone.